# Importing a csv file into postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I have a `*.csv` file which I want to import into my database. basically it looks like that:

```
2013.11.07,11:50,1.35163,1.35167,1.35161,1.35163,15
2013.11.07,11:51,1.35166,1.35173,1.35165,1.35170,21
2013.11.07,11:52,1.35170,1.35170,1.35163,1.35163,11
```

I am using:

```
DROP TABLE table;

CREATE TABLE table
(
id SERIAL primary key,
Date Date,
Time Time,
Open double precision, 
High double precision, 
Low double precision,
Close double precision,
Volume bigint
);

COPY table FROM 'C:\\Users\\user\\EURUSD1.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

However I am getting at the Date:

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "07/11/2013" CONTEXT: COPY
>   eurusd_m1, line 1, column id: "07/11/2013"

I really appreciate your help on how to fix that?

Comment: File format and Table Column order do not match neither do the number of columns. You need to create a table just like the data you want to load.

Comment: @Abhinav Thx for your answer! However, thats not correct! Number of columns of the `create` statement matches the csv(`id` is `SERIAL`). If I am wrong please show me!

Comment: Looking at the error it doesn't seem to be the case. Error says the COPY command is trying to assign Date data to `id` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because `id` is serial doesn't mean it's disregarded when loading - you should be specifying your columns in your `copy` statement, e.g.

```
COPY table (Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
  FROM 'C:\\Users\\user\\EURUSD1.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```